# Creating key-value pairs from SQL table

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I recently came upon a problem where I had the name of many websites in a column(with repetitions) where I had to find out the domains that  exist both as http and https (for example : https://www.google.com and http://www.google.com). The query I made was -

```
`SELECT distinct SPLIT(origin,"://")[OFFSET(1)] as domain 
   FROM "chrome-ux-report.chrome_ux_report.201710" x
     WHERE SPLIT(x.origin,"://")[OFFSET(0)] = "http"
     and  SPLIT(x.origin,"://")[OFFSET(1)] in  
      (SELECT  SPLIT(y.origin,"://")[OFFSET(1)] 
          FROM "chrome-ux-report.chrome_ux_report.201710" y 
            WHERE SPLIT(y.origin,"://")[OFFSET(0)] = "https" ) 
 ORDER BY domain`
```

This query takes O(n^2) time. Knowing python, I could not help but think of  a solution where I could build a new table with the domain as key and the http and https existance as values, for example dict['www.google.com'] = [1,1] or in sql -

```
                Domain     http     https
        www.google.com      1         1
```

which would take O(n) time.Any idea how I could do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is to find all domains which exist in both https and http form. I took the dictionary idea from python. (now i see that its redundant)

Comment: Are you working in MySQL or BigQuery? You've tagged with both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Common Table Expression to pre-select the data should cut a lot of that O(n^2). Not to O(n), but much closer.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT origin
    FROM "chrome-ux-report.chrome_ux_report.201710" x
    WHERE SPLIT(x.origin,"://")[OFFSET(0)] IN ("http", "https")
)
SELECT DISTINCT SPLIT(origin,"://")[OFFSET(1)] AS domain
FROM cte
WHERE SPLIT(cte.origin,"://")[OFFSET(0)] = "http"
AND SPLIT(cte.origin,"://")[OFFSET(1)] IN (
    SELECT SPLIT(cte2.origin,"://")[OFFSET(1)]
    FROM cte AS cte2
    WHERE SPLIT(cte2.origin,"://")[OFFSET(0)] = "https"
)
ORDER BY domain
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm this is an interesting question; I'll just throw my 2 cents. Here's how I'd solve this in BigQuery:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 'http://google.com.br' AS origin UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://google.com.br' AS origin UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.google.com.br' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'http://domain1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://domain2'
)

SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(origin, r'://(.*)') AS domain,
  MAX(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(origin, r'^http[^s]'), TRUE, FALSE)) http,
  MAX(IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(origin, r'^https'), TRUE, FALSE)) https
FROM data
GROUP BY 1
```

Results:

```
Row domain              http    https    
1   www.google.com.br   false   true     
2   domain2             false   true     
3   google.com.br       true    true     
4   domain1             true    false
```

The BigO for this query I suppose is lower than `n^2` but it's probably bigger than `n`: in MySQL a indexed column AFAIK can make the row lookup in `log(n)` (supposing b-index tree) and as this is happening `n` times in this query so end result is `nlog(n)`.

(maybe it's possible to use Hash Maps to reach `O(n)` but I don't know if end result would be `n`)

BigQuery on the other hand does not have indexing; it does have different strategies for managing data as you can see in this [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/08/in-memory-query-execution-in-google-bigquery) (amazing reading).

Still, probably BigQuery can't reach `O(n)` for this task I suppose.

Comment: Your query outputs the domains where only the http versions exist.( In the o/p table, the http column is all true and the https column is all false)

Comment: weird...don't know why this is happening. The data I simulated seems like yours as well. If you run this query with the simulated data you get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?  There's not nearly as much correlation between sub queries this way.

```
Select  sum(if(origin like 'http://%', 1,0 ) as http, 
sum(if(origin like 'https://%', 1,0 ) as https,
Replace(Replace (origin,'http://',''),'https://','') as domain
Group by domain
```

Assuming you really do want MySQL, which seems questionable.